# Unable to sign in to iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

When I attempt to navigate to https://itunesconnect.apple.com I get a spinning wheel and no progress in signing into my account.

I can sign when I open the link in a Chrome Incognito window, but clearing history and browser cache did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Sign into your Apple Developer account here https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/

and follow the link in the member center to iTunes Connect. After doing this, you will again be able to sign into your iTunes Connect account.